# Fail2ban - apache-noscript.conf Filter not working

Tags: apache2, fail2ban, php7

Every night bots try to penetrate my Apache Server:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Output:

```
[Mon Dec 30 02:55:39.098671 2019] [php7:error] [pid 14930] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:62420] script '/var/www/html/test.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I would have expected fail2ban to catch this because there is a filter for it: **apache-noscript.conf**

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s ((AH001(28|30): )?File does not exist|(AH01264: )?script not found or unable to stat): /\S*(php([45]|[.-]cgi)?|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
^%(_apache_error_client)s script '/\S*(php([45]|[.-]cgi)?|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
```

The default jail.conf says per default this:

```
[apache-noscript]
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
```

Does anyone have an idea why fail2ban still does not block access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

[apache-noscript]
enable = true
```